# Can docx4j work in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, docx4j

I want to create an application deployed into the google app engine and I want to use the docx4j library. My application will read in a preexisting docx file (perhaps from a database) and then parse the docx document and replace some content, before outputting the final version as a PDF (also stored in a database)

I know app enine has a quite a few restrictions on what can and cannot run, and I will be using Java to do this. I know it does not allow writing to the filesystem, hence my comment about needing to get the input file and generating the output file into a database.

Does anyone know if the docx4j library, and it's dependencies, will be allowed to run in the app engine environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Java is one of the languages that is supported in both of the Google App Engine environments: standard and flexible. Go to these [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) to check the differences between those and choose the environment suitable for you. You can use Maven to handle your dependencies (the [Docx4J library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j/3.3.6) is available in Maven Repository).

When it comes to storing your files, you have a few options that can be used with Google App Engine app: Google Cloud Datastore, Google Cloud SQL and Google Cloud Storage. Their comparison can be found in GCP docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/storage).